# VS 2015 MSDeployPublish not executing

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-2015, msbuild

I am using VS 2015 and trying to execute a PowerShell after publishing the web application. I have created a publish profile, compiling in release mode and publish method is a file system, then in my project XML I have added a target

```
<Target Name="Mytarget2" AfterTargets="MSDeployPublish">
<Error Text="he name of the publish profile is $(DestinationAppRoot)">
</Error>
</Target>
```

so I am expecting an error message after publishing through visual studio but not getting anything and how can I call PowerShell script if I get it working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> VS 2015 MSDeployPublish not executing

That because you are publishing your project from `File System`. The target "`MSDeployPublish`" is not supported by the `File System`.

> "We currently do not support executing custom targets after publish from VS for the file system protocol. If you publish from the command line the target will be executed however."

So, you could use MSBuild command line to execute this custom target by specify the target, `/t:Mytarget2`:

```
msbuild "YourSolutionFile" /t:Build,Mytarget2 /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=YourPublishFile.pubxml
```

Or you can change settings in VS to build with high verbosity and see whichis the last target to be executed, then you can use it instead of target `MSDeployPublish`, for example, `PipelineTransformPhase`, so the custom target looks like:

```
<Target Name="Mytarget2" AfterTargets="PipelineTransformPhase">
  <Error Text="he name of the publish profile is $(DestinationAppRoot)">
  </Error>
</Target>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I changed the publish target to "Web Deploy" and it is working fine now, how can I execute a powershell file now?

Comment: @Ali, To execute the powershell file, you can check following document for details:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/advanced-enterprise-web-deployment/running-windows-powershell-scripts-from-msbuild-project-files

Comment: @Ali, How about this issue now? Could you execute PS file? If not, let me know your question. If yes, you could accept it as an answer. This can be beneficial to other community members reading this thread.